# Is it possible to record audio on the Pebble smartwatch?

Tags: pebble-watch

The SDK (even the newly released 2.0) is not clear. It seems like you can only record audio from a paired phone, but does anyone have experience capturing audio from Pebble?

Comment: The pebble does not have a microphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide you with an updated answer - it **is** actually possible to record audio with the new Pebble Time smartwatch because it does in fact come with an integrated microphone.

However, the original Pebble smartwatch does not have a microphone.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Dictation API to transcribe voice to text with all the Pebble Time watches (Pebble Time, Pebble Time Steel and Pebble Time Round). Refer to the [Dictation API](http://developer.getpebble.com/guides/pebble-apps/sensors/dictation/).

There is currently no API to directly record audio though and note that the dictation API is not available on the original pebble because it does not have a microphone.

Comment: This is not true for the Pebble Time, which does in fact have a microphone.

Comment: @Baraa do you know of a way that I can get the audio from the Pebble Time mic and store the audio in a .wav file or something? I don't see anything in the docs for getting the actual audio waves.